# iText - Cleaning Up Text in Rectangle without cleaning full row

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm trying to clean up text inside rectangle in pdf document using iText.

Following is the piece of code I’m using:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = null;
PdfStamper stamper = null;
try 
{
    int pageNo = 1;

    List<Float> linkBounds = new ArrayList<Float>();
    linkBounds.add(0, (float) 202.3);
    linkBounds.add(1, (float) 588.6);
    linkBounds.add(2, (float) 265.8);
    linkBounds.add(3, (float) 599.7);

    pdfReader = new PdfReader("Test1.pdf");
    stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream("Test2.pdf"));

    Rectangle linkLocation = new Rectangle(linkBounds.get(0), linkBounds.get(1), linkBounds.get(2), linkBounds.get(3));

    List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
    cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(pageNo, linkLocation, BaseColor.GRAY));
    PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);
    cleaner.cleanUp();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try {
        stamper.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pdfReader.close();
}
```

After executing this piece of code, it’s clearing up entire line of text instead of cleaning up text only inside given rectangle.

To explain things in a better way I have attached pdf documents.

- [input PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zeljo2k8tly7yqi/Test1.pdf?dl=0)
- [output PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3p47odhhp7dc2z/Test2.pdf?dl=0)

In the input pdf, I have highlighted the text to show the rectangle I’m specifying for cleaning up.

And, in the output pdf as you can clearly see that there is grey rectangle but if you notice it cleaned up the whole line of text.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please also share the PDF in question and indicate your iText version.

Comment: I have attached input and output pdf to my original post instead of images. Also, I’m using iText 5.5.5 and iText-Xtra 5.5.5

Comment: This issue is reproducible in 5 out of 10 documents especially in the ones which has bulleted points. If you try to reproduce in a long continuous paragraph, it works fine most of the times.

Comment: *iText 5.5.5 and iText-Xtra 5.5.5* - Please try to use the current versions first. The `PdfCleanUpProcessor` is fairly new to iText and has changed a lot recently. Probably your issue has already been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The files `input.pdf` and `output.pdf` the OP originally presented did not allow to reproduce the issue but instead seemed not at all to match. Thus, there was an original answer essentially demonstrating that the issue could not be reproduced.*

*The second set of files `Test1.pdf` and `Test2.pdf`, though, did allow to reproduce the issue, giving rise to the updated answer...*

### Updated answer referring to the OP's second set of sample files

There indeed is an issue in the current (up to 5.5.8) iText clean-up code: In case of tagged files some methods of `PdfContentByte` used here introduced extra instructions into the content stream which actually damaged it and relocated some text in the eyes of PDF viewers which ignored the damage.

In more detail:

`PdfCleanUpContentOperator.writeTextChunks` used `canvas.setCharacterSpacing(0)` and `canvas.setWordSpacing(0)` to initially set the character and word spacing to 0. Unfortunately these methods in case of tagged files check whether the canvas under construction currently is in a text object and (if not) start a text object. This check depends on a local flag set by `beginText`; but during clean-up text objects are not started using that method. Thus, `writeTextChunks` here inserts an extra `"BT 1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm"` sequence damaging the stream and relocating the following text.

```
private void writeTextChunks(Map<Integer, Float> structuredTJoperands, List<PdfCleanUpContentChunk> chunks, PdfContentByte canvas,
                             float characterSpacing, float wordSpacing, float fontSize, float horizontalScaling) throws IOException {
    canvas.setCharacterSpacing(0);
    canvas.setWordSpacing(0);
    ...
```

`PdfCleanUpContentOperator.writeTextChunks` instead should use hand-crafted `Tc` and `Tw` instructions to not trigger this side effect.

```
private void writeTextChunks(Map<Integer, Float> structuredTJoperands, List<PdfCleanUpContentChunk> chunks, PdfContentByte canvas,
                             float characterSpacing, float wordSpacing, float fontSize, float horizontalScaling) throws IOException {
    if (Float.compare(characterSpacing, 0.0f) != 0 && Float.compare(characterSpacing, -0.0f) != 0) {
        new PdfNumber(0).toPdf(canvas.getPdfWriter(), canvas.getInternalBuffer());
        canvas.getInternalBuffer().append(Tc);
    }
    if (Float.compare(wordSpacing, 0.0f) != 0 && Float.compare(wordSpacing, -0.0f) != 0) {
        new PdfNumber(0).toPdf(canvas.getPdfWriter(), canvas.getInternalBuffer());
        canvas.getInternalBuffer().append(Tw);
    }
    canvas.getInternalBuffer().append((byte) '[');
```

With this change in place the OP's new sample file "Test1.pdf" is properly redacted by the sample code

```
@Test
public void testRedactJavishsTest1() throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    try (   InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Test1.pdf");
            OutputStream result = new FileOutputStream(new File(OUTPUTDIR, "Test1-redactedJavish.pdf")) )
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, result);

        List<Float> linkBounds = new ArrayList<Float>();
        linkBounds.add(0, (float) 202.3);
        linkBounds.add(1, (float) 588.6);
        linkBounds.add(2, (float) 265.8);
        linkBounds.add(3, (float) 599.7);

        Rectangle linkLocation1 = new Rectangle(linkBounds.get(0), linkBounds.get(1), linkBounds.get(2), linkBounds.get(3));
        List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
        cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, linkLocation1, BaseColor.GRAY));

        PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);
        cleaner.cleanUp();

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

*([RedactText.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup/RedactText.java))*

### Original answer referring to the OP's original sample files

I just tried to reproduce your issue using this test method

```
@Test
public void testRedactJavishsText() throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    try (   InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("input.pdf");
            OutputStream result = new FileOutputStream(new File(OUTPUTDIR, "input-redactedJavish.pdf")) )
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, result);

        List<Float> linkBounds = new ArrayList<Float>();
        linkBounds.add(0, (float) 200.7);
        linkBounds.add(1, (float) 547.3);
        linkBounds.add(2, (float) 263.3);
        linkBounds.add(3, (float) 558.4);

        Rectangle linkLocation1 = new Rectangle(linkBounds.get(0), linkBounds.get(1), linkBounds.get(2), linkBounds.get(3));
        List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
        cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, linkLocation1, BaseColor.GRAY));

        PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);
        cleaner.cleanUp();

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

*([RedactText.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/pdfcleanup/RedactText.java))*

For your source PDF looking like this

[image: input.pdf]

the result was

[image: input-redactedJavish.pdf]

and not your

[image: output.pdf]

I even re-tested using the iText versions 5.5.5 you mention in a comment and also 5.5.4, but in all cases I got the correct result.

Thus, I cannot reproduce your issue.

---

I had a closer look at your output.pdf. It is a bit peculiar, in particular it does not contain certain blocks typical for PDFs created or manipulated by current iText versions. Furthermore the content streams look extremely different.

Thus, I assume that after iText redacted your file some other tool post-processed and in doing so damaged it.

In particular the page content instructions preparing the insertion of the redacted line look like this in your input.pdf:

```
q
0.24 0 0 0.24 113.7055 548.04 cm
BT
0.0116 Tc
45 0 0 45 0 0 Tm
/TT5 1 Tf
[...] TJ
```

and like this in the version I received directly from iText:

```
q
0.24 0 0 0.24 113.7055 548.04 cm
BT
0.0116 Tc
45 0 0 45 0 0 Tm
/TT5 1 Tf
0 Tc
0 Tw 
[...] TJ
```

but the corresponding lines in your output.pdf look like this

```
BT
1 0 0 1 113.3 548.5 Tm
0 Tc
BT
1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm
0 Tc 
[...] TJ
```

Here the instructions in your output.pdf are

- invalid as inside a text object `BT ... ET` there may be no other text object but you have two `BT` operations following each other without an `ET` inbetween;
- effectively positioning the text at 0, 0 if a PDF viewer ignores the error mentioned above.

And indeed, if you look at the bottom of your output.pdf page you'll see:

[image: output.pdf, page bottom]

So if my assumption that there is some other program post-processing the iText result, is correct, you should repair that post-processor.

If there is no such post-processor, you seem not to have the officially published iText version but something altogether different.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me try to run it with latest iText Version. Also, even for me the result is inconsistent i.e. sometimes it works fine and sometime not.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my original post with complete example code. Also, I upgraded to latest version 5.5.8 but still I’m experiencing the issue. In addition, I have updated the input and output file, with the new cleanup location as this is getting reproduced consistently. Thanks again for putting your time into it and helping me out.

Comment: @Javish do you have a post-processor as I conjectured? The differences in the stream cannot be otherwise explained.

Comment: @Javish I just could reproduce the issue with your new set of files. I'm looking into that. With your original set of files, though, you **A** made it impossible to reproduce the issue, and **B** showed that you try to eliminate the traces of your iText using from the result PDF. I'm not sure that that is in sync with the iText licensing conditions.

Comment: It’s good to know that at least you were able to reproduce the issue. Also, as you asked for post processor, I’m not doing any kind of post processing. The example code given in my updated post yesterday is a java standalone program which doesn’t do anything after cleanup.

Comment: @Javish I assumed a post-processor for two reasons: **a** your first pair of sample files created similar looking pages but internally looked very different, a difference beyond everything the clean-up could do; thus, you either had a pre-processor or a post-processor. **b** your output.pdf did not contain the more obvious signs of a Pdf generated or manipulated by iText. Thus, you either had a post-processor or a manipulated iText library.

Comment: @Javish As it does not make sense to test with a manipulated library and then post a stackoverflow question with respect to the original one, I obviously assumed a post-processor. As you claim you don't have a post- processor, though, you must have been using a manipulated iText for creating your output.pdf from the first set of sample files.

Comment: I don’t now for sure that why the issue was not replicable in my first set of files because I’m using same library and it’s the standard one downloaded from iText site. But, as I said earlier that for few files the issue is intermittent. The reason I had updated input and output files is because I was able to reproduce the issue consistently with these new set of files.

Comment: Also, to fix this do I have to get the source and make changes as you suggested or I can get a nightly build in case there is any. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: @Javish As mentioned above your original files (input.pdf, output.pdf) were so different from each other that something else than clean-up must have been applied to it. Furthermore the final result has not been created by an iText version as downloaded from the iText site as that version leaves certain signs inside the document which output.pdf misses. If you really are not aware of additional processing steps or manipulated library versions, you had better start checking your whole software stack, class path and all, because in that case your runtime environment must be seriously compromised.

Comment: I know clearly that there is no additional processing going on because it’s exactly the same code which I have mentioned in my post. I’m running it as a standalone program, so there is no question of post processing as of now. The only piece of executable code is the one posted in this question other than that nothing is there in the code. Will try to include your changes and test it out.

Comment: I changed the iText_xtra API code as per your suggestion. It works like a charm. Thank You